# CLI program exits before retrieving Parse Results

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, parse-platform

My OS X CLI program exits before retrieving results from an asynchronous Parse query. The same code does not happen in an iOS app (because an iOS app has a GUI?). Is there a way to handle handle the results without the program exiting prematurely?

```
#import "Bolts.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        [Parse setApplicationId:@"my parse app id"
                      clientKey:@"my parse app client key"];

        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Wizard"];
        [query whereKey:@"house" equalTo:@"Hufflepuff"]

        [[query findObjectsInBackground] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task)
        {
            for (PFObject *wizard in task.result)
            {
                // does not go here, program exits immidiately
                // ??
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *semaphore* to prevent your main function finishing until your asynchronous block has run. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597081/only-continue-loop-if-method-has-finished/25598918#25598918) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31850598/how-to-execute-a-block-immediately-in-a-function/31851702#31851702) (and others) for the general details and issues to watch.

HTH

Comment: Looks like using semaphores is the way to go. Thank you.